# How Text Attribute display in Layerd Navigation in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, layered-navigation

Magento2 in creating custom attribute like as 'event-date' type is text and set Layered is yes but it's not working.

[image]
**I want to display Event Date attribute in layered navigation with two dates between products filter. Thanx in advance.**

Comment: Did you set your attribute to Filterable (with results) ?

Comment: Yes, i already did.

Comment: did you end up finding your answer?

Comment: No..............